# Angular2 check re-entered password

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I have angular2 form as:

```
this.registerForm = formBuilder.group({
        'name': ['', Validators.required],
        'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.pattern("[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"), Validators.required])],
        'password': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required])],
        'repassword': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), Validators.required])]
    });
```

But I am unable to figure out how to check repassword with password and throw error msg.

** I followed answer of [Angular 2 form validating for repeat password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474991/angular-2-form-validating-for-repeat-password) but unable to include ControlGroup.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your custom validator to compare `password` and `repassword` fields.

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

function comparePassword(c: AbstractControl) {
    return c.get('password').value === c.get(' repassword').value
}

this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    email: [''],
    passwordgroup: this.fb.group({
        password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        repassword: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    },  comparePassword)
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for trplying, in this link it is using template driven form and I am using form builder wont it be a issue ?

Comment: You can create a custom validator for form builder as well.

Comment: checking, Thanks for replying :)

Comment: I am getting following errors: Error: Cannot find control with name: 'password' Error: Cannot find control with name: 'password' and TypeError: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined.