# angular4: custom 'equals' validation using valueChanges observable

Tags: angular, validation, observable

I needed a validation that checks if `email` equals `Email Confirm`.
For this I created a custom validation that looks like

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export function ValidateEqual( equals: string ) {
  return ( control: AbstractControl ): ValidationErrors | null => {

    const equalsField = control.root.get( equals )
    if ( equalsField ) {

      equalsField.valueChanges.subscribe( value => {
        console.log( 'observable fired', value );
        // control.updateValueAndValidity( { onlySelf: true  , emitEvent: false } );
      } );
      if ( control.value !== equalsField.value ) {
        return { equals: true };
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

and my form looks like

```
this.loginForm = this.fb.group( {
  password: [ '', [
    Validators.required,
  ] ],
  email: [ '', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.email,
  ] ],
  emailConfirm: [ '', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.email,
    ValidateEqual( 'email' ),
  ] ]
} );
```

So I am passing the field to check equality with as an argument in `ValidateEqual()`. That works fine.

The following scenario fails:

1)

Email: mattijs@foo.nl

Confirm Email: mattijs@food.nl

*now Confirm email shows an error that it is not equal to `Email'. Correct.

2)

*now I change the `email` field to match the `confirm email` field.

Email: mattijs@food.nl

Confirm Email: mattijs@food.nl

*The error on the `confirm email` field doesn't disappear because it is not aware of any change.

The issue I have is, that I am trying to use the `valueChanges` observable on the equals field to have the `control` field to re-validate, but when I enable `control.updateValueAndValidity()` it is subscribing exponentially on each keypress and the browser will crash. IT does notify the `email confirm` field to re-validate, so it almost works...almost.

Does anyone have an idea how to only have it subscribe once and make it re-validate the `control` field without subscribing again (and again...)?

Comment: check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487413/password-and-confirm-password-field-validation-angular2-reactive-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ValidatorFn` placed on a `FormControl` will obviously only be checked when that FormControl's value changes. What we want is to check when either `email` or `emailConfirm` changes. To achieve this, we need to validate the FormGroup instead of just a FormControl. Because a `ValidatorFn` receives an `AbstractControl` that means our function can receive a FormGroup, FormControl or FormArray.

```
static matches(form: AbstractControl){
    return form.get('email').value == form.get('emailConfirm').value ? null : {equals: true};
}
```

Now, in your component, you still need to add this validator and it's a bit different:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({...}, {validator: CustomValidator.matches});
```

As you can see we can pass it a second object as an argument which takes validators for the entire `FormGroup`

In your template you would check to see if the entire form has the equals error instead of an individual FormControl:

```
<div *ngIf="form.hasError('equals')">The emails don't match</div>
```

Comment: though, in FormControl you can use **root** or **parent** fields to get your second FormControl

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way of checking two email are same or not
in your validate equal class write this code

```
export class emailValidation {
    static matchEmail(AC: AbstractControl){
        let email=AC.get('email').value;
        let emailConfirm=AC.get('emailConfirm').value;
        if(email!=emailConfirm){
            console.log(false);
        }
    }
}
```

and in your component add this code

```
this.loginForm = this.fb.group( {
  password: [ '', [
    Validators.required,
  ] ],
  email: [ '', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.email,
  ] ],
  emailConfirm: [ '', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.email,
  ] ]
},
{
    validator:passwordValidation.matchPassword
    } );
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you take a look at [ngx-validation](https://github.com/ReactiveCore-com/ngx-validation) on github.
It is a small open source lib, You can either use it directly or fork it, or simply see how they did it there:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the good examples. I makes sense to do this on the form and not on a formControl since it doesn't know how to react/respond to other controls.

I made a slight tweak so that I can control the fields that are compared in the Equal validator.
I also set the error on the `field2` control so that I don't have to add a separate error message somewhere under my fields (I use Material design mat-form-fields):

```
interface IEmailMatchFields {
  field1: string;
  field2: string;
}
export class EmailMatch {

  fields: IEmailMatchFields;
  constructor( fields: IEmailMatchFields ) {
    this.fields = fields;
  }
  emailMatches( form: AbstractControl ) {

    if ( this.fields ) {
      if ( form.get( this.fields.field1 ).value == form.get( this.fields.field2 ).value ) {
        form.get( this.fields.field2 ).setErrors( { 'emailNotEq': false } );
        form.get( this.fields.field2 ).updateValueAndValidity( { onlySelf: true } );
        return null;
      } else {
        form.get( this.fields.field2 ).setErrors( { 'emailNotEq': true } );
        return { emailNotEq: true };
      }
    }
  }
}

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  emailMatch: EmailMatch;
  registerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.emailMatch = new EmailMatch( { field1: 'email', field2: 'emailConfirm' } );
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.registerForm = this.fb.group( {
      password: [ '', [
        Validators.required,
      ] ],
      email: [ '', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email,
      ] ],
      emailConfirm: [ '', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email,
      ] ]
    }, {
      validator: this.emailMatch.emailMatches.bind( this.emailMatch )
    } );
  }
}
```

I guess instead of `field1` and `field2` you could also pass in references of the 2 formcontrols but then you have to add the formcontrols to your formgroup etc..
I think sending the keys works fine.