# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerControl' of null

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to validate new password and confirm password using angular 4. I am new in Angular. I have tried different methods but I am getting this error everytime. Please guide me. Please help me where am i getting wrong. Help me solve this error so that my code works.

password.ts

```
    import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/operator/delay';
    import 'rxjs/operator/mergeMap';
    import 'rxjs/operator/switchMap';
    import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
        selector: 'page-password',
        templateUrl: 'password.html',
    })
    export class PasswordPage {

        constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private http: Http, public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {
        }

        ionViewDidLoad() {
            console.log('ionViewDidLoad PasswordPage');
        }

        public Credentials: FormGroup;

        ngOnInit() {
            this.Credentials = new FormGroup({});
            this.Credentials.addControl('Password', new FormControl('', [Validators.required]));
            this.Credentials.addControl('Confirmation', new FormControl('', [Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.validateAreEqual.bind(this)])]));
        }

        private validateAreEqual(fieldControl: FormControl) {
            return fieldControl.value === this.Credentials.get("Password").value ? null : { NotEqual: true };
        }
```

password.html

```
    <ion-content padding>
      <div class="loginContainer">
        <div class="centerLogo">
          <h1>
            <a href="#">
              <img src="images/logomaster.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
          </h1>
        </div>
        <form #fm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="test(fm)" novalidate>
          <ul id="tabs">

            <li (click)="showemail=false">
              <a id="tab2">Set your PIN</a>
            </li>

          </ul>
          <div class="form-group row" formGroupName="passwords" id="tab2C">
            <div class="form-group">
              <ion-item>
                <ion-input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" title="Please enter your password"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <ion-item>
                <ion-input type="password" class="form-control" formControlName="confirmedPassword" title="Please re-enter your password"></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </div>
            <div class="btnRow">
              <input class="loginBtn" type="submit" id="phoneBtn" value="Continue" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some problems in your template, first of all you have not marked your formgroup in your template, and then you are declaring a `formGroupName` named `passwords`, that doesn't exist in your form.

Your form should therefore looks something like this:

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="test(fm)" [formGroup]="Credentials">
  <ul id="tabs">
    <li (click)="showemail=false">
      <a id="tab2">Set your PIN</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="form-group row" id="tab2C">
    <div class="form-group">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="password"formControlName="Password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="password"formControlName="Confirmation"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item *ngIf="Credentials.hasError('NotEqual', 'Confirmation')">
        NOT SAME
      </ion-item>
    </div>
    <div class="btnRow">
      <input class="loginBtn" type="submit" id="phoneBtn" value="Continue" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wfc7na?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)**

I want to point out though, that this validation message will not be shown if you start editing the `Password` field, after matching it with the confirm field. To have this work both ways, I'd suggest a custom validator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43493648/6294072

Comment: Thanks @AJT_82 it really helped me realize my mistake. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: You are welcome! Since it solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of this answer, which marks the question as solved :)