# How do validate multiple fields as one in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I'm building an Angular 5 form. I have a requirement for contact information on my form (email or phone). Either an email address OR a phone number is required, but not both. How would I create a custom validator for this scenario? From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) it seems that validators are responsible for just one control, whereas my validator would need to be aware of multiple controls to check all their values.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
       'name': [null, [Validators.required]],
       'email': [null, []], // A user can provide email OR phone, but
       'phone': [null, []], // both are not required. How would you do this?
   });
}
```

Comment: You'd use the same custom validator for each, but you'd use a reference to each control and return true if one or the other was used. Here's a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487413/password-and-confirm-password-field-validation-angular2-reactive-forms that uses the same idea to validate a password. Still, two form controls are checked to create a group validator.

Comment: not completely working yet, try to enhance this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9effym?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possible solution is declaring a function that takes as an argument the form itself, for example:

```
    export function emailAndPhone() {
      return (form: FormGroup): {[key: string]: any} => {
        return (form.value.phone && form.value.email) ||
               (!form.value.phone && !form.value.email) 
                  ? { emailAndPhoneError : true } 
                  : null;
      };
    }
```

Set the validator function to your form definition using the `validator` extras:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
       'name': [null, [Validators.required]],
       'email': [null, []], // A user can provide email OR phone, but
       'phone': [null, []], // both are not required. How would you do this?
   }, { validator: emailAndPhone() });
}
```

If you need to recognize when the validation has detected an invalid input just make sure that `emailAndPhoneError` that was defined earlier is present on the form error list.  Like this

```
*ngIf="myForm.hasError('emailAndPhoneError')" //true means invalid
```

Comment: And where does emailAndPhoneError come from here?

Comment: `{ emailAndPhoneError : true }` is the return value from `emailAndPhone()` function.  It is only returned when your condition is invalid, otherwise it returns null.

Comment: @DanielC. Yes, this will be a good starting point to build from. Thanks.