# Cannot read property of undefined Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to make a custom validator for password but I don't get why I get the following error
 **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'f' of undefined**

Below is my code:

```
registerForm: FormGroup;
submitted = false;
constructor(private Auth:AuthService, private router:Router,private 
formBuilder:FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  userName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(6),Validators.maxLength(30),Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')])],
  email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
  password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])],
  cpassword: ['', Validators.required,passwordMatch()] //paswordMatch triggers the error
},);
}

get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }

function  passwordMatch() { 
if(this.f != undefined){
let passwordInput = this.f.password,
   passwordConfirmationInput = this.f.cpassword;
if (passwordInput.value !== passwordConfirmationInput.value) {
 return passwordConfirmationInput.setErrors({notequal: true})
}
else {
   return passwordConfirmationInput.setErrors(null);
}
}
}
```

Comment: just use ``passwordMatch()`` instead of ``function passwordMatch()``

Comment: I use function because passwordmatch is outside of component class

Comment: won't that affect your scope of ``f`` ?

Comment: I did as you say,still the same error, wherever I declare  that method or function still the same output

Comment: I would create a subgroup for passwords and apply the validator there. Because what if user changes the first password after entering confirmation. The form would be valid, even though passwords do not match.

Comment: Here's one option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43493648/6294072

Comment: I have a variable submitted which turns true only after the submit button is pressed, and in html I check for errors only when that variable is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is `undefined` in your function, therefore you cannot reference it.

What I would add a sub formgroup, that would track both the value of password and confirm password, but if you want to go this route, modify your code as such:

```
// ...
// see the brackets also around the validators! No need to use Validators.compose
cpassword: ['', [Validators.required, passwordMatch]]
// ...
```

Then you would access the form group with `parent`. Also you need to return either `null` (valid) or an error:

```
function passwordMatch(input: FormControl) {
  if (input.parent) {
    let passwordInput = input.parent.get('password');
    if (passwordInput.value !== input.value) {
      return { notequal: true }
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

**DEMO**: **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zjq5ve?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

But with this, we need to remember, if user modifies password field after modifying the confirmpassword and the passwords do not match, the form will still be considered valid. Here's a way to avoid this: [password and confirm password field validation angular2 reactive forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487413/password-and-confirm-password-field-validation-angular2-reactive-forms/43493648#43493648)

Comment: Sorry for late answer I needed to take a break, I will make a subgroup but  for password and confirm password but first I want to see this one working but still is not,I updated the method as you said and I got the following error: ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable.

Comment: ok seems I forgot to put a bracket and everything was fine, sorry but I am trying to learn Angular and today spent too much time on PC and I am tired ,Thank you for help.

Comment: No problem Gabriel, glad I could help. Have a good weekend and do some resting :P

Comment: Could you please help me a bit more to understand how the nested group will work?Shall I have a different implementation in my html component except let's say:  create a <div class="form-group" formcontrolname="passwords"> and inside div to implement form groups for password and cpassword  and ofc at the end of div to have another div for showing error, shall I change something except of what I mention above?

Comment: easier with showing, this should be quite clear? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-69peym?file=src/app/app.component.ts From what I gather from your comment you seem to be totally on the right track :)

Comment: How am I supposed to print the errors for the password field for exemple:<div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
                            <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.minlength">Password must be at least 6 characters</div>   because right now I get cannot read property of errors of undifined

Comment: Ok I got how to acces control from a nested group but something is not working properly, my html implementation is as you said, however method is working fine but actually after I write something in password field and confirm password field, no matter what I get no error even if the password are not the same

Comment: Could you take the stackblitz I created and reproduce the issue there and I'm happy to take a look at it :)

Comment: Ok then I will put the whole code of the registration form so I will try to reproduce it there

Comment: Ok take  a look now ,https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-69peym?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts  ,Edit: type something in password field, then you see the message password do not match, type something in cpassword field then error is gone

Comment: You need to fork it, I'm seeing the same stackblitz I created.

Comment: Ooops sorry I forgot, try now

Comment: That is not an editor view, and still seems to be the same blitz I created :D

Comment: If I go to this url it shows me the stackblitz with all updates I've done:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8whvkp

Comment: You are having the error message inside `cp.errors` that won't work, since if the `cpassword` field is valid, i.e is filled, the error message of equal passwords won't show, since the validator is on the formgroup, not the formcontrol: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjnqf6?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Ah ty, but I remember that I had this way implemented  too but probably at thaat time had something else not working...almost everytime I fix a thing and another one broken, tought that way will work too since everything was inside the div of passwords , ty:D

Answer (score 0):

you can use **input .root** to get access to the parent of a control (your registerForm) try this, no need for f function

```
 function  passwordMatch(input: FormControl) { 
  if(input.root != undefined){
  let passwordInput = input.root.controls.password,
  passwordConfirmationInput = input.root.controls.cpassword;
  if (passwordInput.value !== passwordConfirmationInput.value) {
   return passwordConfirmationInput.setErrors({notequal: true})
  }
  else {
    return passwordConfirmationInput.setErrors(null);
  }
 }
```

...

```
cpassword: ['', Validators.required, passwordMatch]
```

Comment: I get an error at compile time that control is not a property of AbstractControl

Comment: try input.root['controls'] instead of .controls

Comment: I get this error when I type in confirm password field ERROR Error: Expected validator to return Promise or Observable. Is there a problem with my validator method?

Comment: I figured out what was the problem , already had that issue again earlier , but still after all changes as you said I get no compile error but that function is still throwing an error , cannot read password of unfined...