# Reactive Forms Angular - Cannot read property 'group' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Not similar to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235952/cannot-read-property-of-undefined-reactive-forms`

StackBlitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rbjwcd-wtrevw

Having issues with the above demo. I am trying to get the form builder to work with models as per the example. The issue is with the `.group` property.

```
contactForm: FormGroup;

  createFormGroupWithBuilderAndModel(formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      personalData: formBuilder.group(new PersonalData()),
      requestType: '',
      text: ''
    });
  }
```

I think the issue might be not initialising the form on the return like:

```
this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group
```

Can anybody get this to run?

Comment: *this.formBuilder* is null

Comment: In constructor ```this.contactForm = this.createFormGroupWithBuilderAndModel(this.formBuilder);```

Comment: Any reason you're passing formBuilder into `createFormGroupWithBuilderAndModel` rather than using `this.formBuilder` directly? (I assume it's me missing something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixing your stackblitz...

```
 constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.contactForm = this.createFormGroupWithBuilderAndModel(formBuilder);
  }
```

Comment: Np, glad to help you. Maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers ;-)