# Change angular11 form validation status when using FormGroup, FormBuilder and Validators

Tags: angular, angular11

```
onblurRePass(event:any){
    this.valOfRePass = this.empProperties.repassword;
    console.log("Pass Val: "+this.valOfPass + " RePass Val: "+this.valOfRePass);

    if(this.valOfPass == this.valOfRePass){
      this.matchPassword = 'matched';
      this.addForm.status = 'VALID'; // need to change this status
    }
    else{
      this.matchPassword = 'unmatched';
      this.addForm.status = 'INVALID';  //need to change this status
    }
  }
```

Error: Cannot assign to 'status' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)

Comment: I suggest you to create a custom validator that compares `valOfPass` and `valOfRePass`.

Comment: @N.F.Please post your answer/working code with custom validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options available.

1. A form is invalid if it has errors so you can simply use `setErrors()` to update the form

```
  onblurRePass() {
    this.valOfRePass = this.empProperties.repassword;
    console.log(
      'Pass Val: ' + this.valOfPass + ' RePass Val: ' + this.valOfRePass
    );

    if (this.valOfPass == this.valOfRePass) {
      this.matchPassword = 'matched';
      this.addForm.setErrors(null)
    } else {
      this.matchPassword = 'unmatched';
       this.addForm.setErrors({'mismatched': true})
    }
  }
```

[**Sample Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pb1mw5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

2. The other option is to simply use a custom validator [password and confirm password field validation angular2 reactive forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487413/password-and-confirm-password-field-validation-angular2-reactive-forms)

Comment: I would opt for the custom validator. Just removing errors means, that all other types of validation errors you may have added (like a minimum length), would be removed too.

Comment: @JanRecker Not entirely true. If you check I have applied the validator on the `addForm`. So only that FormGroup is affected. The children formGroup are not affected, You can check the updated demo. I have added a minLength of 3

Comment: @OwenKelvin it is working, can you please describe what is "get"  before function name "valOfPass()"?

Comment: `get` here has been used as a `getter` to "get" the property "valOfPass". This was my approach to make the demo work but in your case you may have used a different approach. Also I think you may need to have a look at some articles to understand the concept of "getters and setters" e.g here  https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_accessors.asp

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this, is to create a custom validator and use it on the `FormGroup({})` itself not on the `FormControl()` of the password.

This validator `directive` class takes the two `FormControl()`s as input and checks for their values if they match or not. So the validator must be on a higher level than the two `FormControl()`s that it is validating.

I hope this is well informative and helpful for your situation.

[here's the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/validate-password-equal-confirm)

Comment: thank you for the answer. Can you please help with working code?

Comment: Dear Mr. @MuhammadBilal, I edited my answer and added a code example on [stackblitz.com]. I hope this fulfills your inquiry. I wish the best